# deploy non-nextjs edge-runtime to vercel

Tags: serverless, vercel

Recently I've been playing around with the edge-runtime and finally set things to work normally on my local environment with different routes path handled by some of my custom implementations under fetch event. and these are running under [edge-runtime](https://edge-runtime.vercel.app/cli)

And with some digging around, to be able to deploy what I've made to Vercel I have to convert my project to nextjs and exposed the config to ensure it to run on the experimental-edge runtime

What I want to ask here is

- Is there a way I can deploy my edge-runtime API to Vercel without having to convert my project to NextJS

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Next is required.

use Cloudflare Workers instead for legacy fetch handler support